# How can I put a span tag around some text in a code tag?

Tags: jquery, html

Hello and thanks for taking your time to help me.

**This is my page setup:**

```
<code class="form-control" contenteditable="true" style="height: 100%; min-height: 100px"></code>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/HashTagList.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        HastTagLocation('form-control');

    });

function HastTagLocation(Controll) {
    var controller = $('.' + Controll);
    controller.keyup(function () {

    })
}
</script>
```

For everytime I write a ! I want to put that and the following text into a div/span tag.

**Like this:**

```html
<code>
Hello !how are you !today
</code>
```

**To this:**

```css
span.mark {
  background-color: #808080;
}
```

```html
<code>
    Hello <span class="mark">!how</span> are you <span class="mark">!today</span>
    </code>
```

Is it posible in someway to make this?

Comment: Probably worth trying to do it will a regex replace on the text content. Give it a try, come back when you get stuck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use regex replace function to do this...

```
// Get the code element.
var e = $('code');
// Get the text content.
var text = e.text();
// Replace the matches and wrap them with span tag.
var text = text.replace(/(\![a-zA-Z]*)/g, '<span class="mark">$1</span>');
// Set the html of the original element.
e.html(text);
```

You will need to review the regex and decide if it works for you. Are the moment it works for `!` followed by 0 or more *letters*. If you need other characters then you need to adjust the regex.

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/oyqk3xe1/1)

Comment: Add `contenteditable` to that, and an event handler, and replacing the html makes the cursor jump to start, and a few other issues.

Comment: If i do this : <code contenteditable="true"> I run into a problem. every time i type something it the cursor jumps back to the start. Like this http://jsfiddle.net/oyqk3xe1/3/

Comment: I didn't know that was the questions, but there are lots of ways to work around the issue. For example, like SO does with a  preview pane, and only apply the change on focus lost. Having it edit as you type (and remember caret) is not impossible, but would require a great deal of work. Too much I feel for an SO answer

Answer (score 0):

An easy workaround would be to put '!' at the beginning of the word and say '#' at the end. Then insert the following code (not tested myself but should work):

```
return $(this).text().replace("!", "<span class='mark'>"); 
return $(this).text().replace("#", "</span>");
```

You could combine them in two but that's the most simple solution I can think of. Tell me how it goes.

Comment: `<span class='mark'>` should be `<span class='mark'>!` since he wants to retain `!`

Comment: But this does not completely provide the solution.. See his expected output.. Also you need to say when he should apply this.. and `#` is not what he want.. He has to get it from `space`

Comment: I agree, just a very easy workaround. With your suggestion in place it should provide him with the correct output, no?